# Validate const String plus any variable text

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express, middleware

I am using a middleware for express in nodejs which validates if the route is different from 'login'or 'signin' but I also need to validate that it is different from the activation route plus my token ('/api/activation/+token'), that is, I have the following:

```
If(req.path ¡= '/api/login'  && req.path != '/api/signin'){
//execute verification middleware
}else{
//allow access to the route
//exclude verification
}
```

So I need to also exclude the activation path plus my token from verification.
It works in the following way:

```
//(assuming eyJajau is my token)
If(req.path ¡= '/api/login'  && req.path != '/api/signin' && req.path != '/api/activate/eyJajau'){
//execute middleware
} else{
//allow access to the route
}
```

But the problem is that the token changes every time, so I need to my 'if' statement validate if the string is different from my path plus any word, it would be something like this:

```
/api/activation/  +  any word and number
```

In other words, every Sting that contains '/api/active/' and then whatever should go to the "élse" statement
I think it could be with regex, but I don't know how.

So what I need is to validate that the req.path is different from the activation path plus any Sting.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude requests with `/api/activation/` followed by any character or a number, you could use the following [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp): `/\/api\/activate\/\w+/`. I would also invert the logic, so your code could look something like:

```
if (req.path === '/api/login' ||
    req.path === '/api/signin' ||
    /\/api\/activate\/\w+/.test(req.path) {
    // allow access
} else {
    // validate/verificate request
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, I was testing the same regex, but my error was that I was using the '&&' operator instead of '||' just to learn something else ...
Do you think it can be achieved using the '&&' operator?
How would it be like this?

Comment: @crazyProgrammer: A logical `( NOT (a) AND NOT (b) )` is the same as `NOT ( (a) OR (b) )`

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex & make sure to anchor it at beginning and end:

```
If( req.path === '/api/login'
 || req.path === '/api/signin'
 || req.path.match(/^\/api\/activate\/\w+$/)
) {
    // allow access to the route
} else{
    // execute middleware to authenticate or verify user
}
```

You can shorten it to a single ORed regex to check the path if you like:

```
If(path.match(/^\/api\/(login|signin|activate\/\w+)$/)) {
    // allow access to the route
} else{
    // execute middleware to authenticate or verify user
}
```

Comment: I've been looking for something like the second option, but when I try your example it won't let me pass. It always goes to the else statement.
I am using '/api/activate/token' as path

Comment: That means your activate token has some other chars besides word chars. Try this regex: `/^\/api\/(login|signin|activate\/.*)$/`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best way, but I found a solution for my problem, using substring.
as follows:

```
if( req.path != '/api/login' && req.path != '/api/signin' && req.path.substring(0,21) != '/api/activateaccount/' ){
  //validate verificate reques
}else{
  //allow access
}
```

What do you think about that?